# setGroupHeaders of JQGrid for column headers grouping is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid to represent tabular data. I want to group 2 column headers. I am using setGroupHeaders method of JQGrid, but it's not working. Even there is no any error in console.
Here is my code. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

...

```
jQuery("#DataGridTable").jqGrid({

    url: '/Home/ViewDeferredAccount',
    contentType: "application/json",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Key','Sector Code', 'Route Code', 'EL1', 'EL2', 'Payment Cmp Code', 'Revenue Cmp Code'],
    colModel: [

    { name: 'DEFRD_REV_AC_KEY', index: 'DEFRD_REV_AC_KEY', width: 40, stype: 'text' },
    { name: 'SECTOR_CD', index: 'SECTOR_CD', width: 180, stype: 'text' },
    { name: 'ROUTE_CD', index: 'ROUTE_CD', width: 150 },
    { name: 'EL1_AC_CD', index: 'EL1_AC_CD', width: 140, sortable: false },
    { name: 'EL2_AC_CD', index: 'EL2_AC_CD', width: 140, sortable: false },
    { name: 'PYMN_CMP_CD', index: 'PYMN_CMP_CD', width: 180 },
    { name: 'RVN_CMP_CD', index: 'RVN_CMP_CD', width: 180 }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Maintain and Setup Deferred Account",
});
```

...

```
jQuery("#DataGridTable").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: true,
        groupHeaders: [
          { startColumnName: 'EL1_AC_CD', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Sector Code' }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: you should include more full JavaScript code. It's important to know the relation of `setGroupHeaders` to the code which creates jqGrid. Typical error: one try to call `setGroupHeaders` *before* creating the grid, because one place creating the grid inside of document ready handle, but the call of `setGroupHeaders` is outside of the handler. In any way you should always write which version and which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7) of jqGrid you use.

Comment: I am using JQGrid 4.4.0. Which version should I use to get column headers grouping functionality?

Comment: jqGrid is a retro version. I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop. You can try it just by changing the URLs to the jqGrid files. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). The current version of free jqGrid is 4.11.0, but I will publish 4.11.1 this week with one small bug fix. You can use RawGit URLs like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>`